# Want to find the product of a sublist in Java

Tags: java

a large array of thousand integers have been loaded and i want to find the largest product of 4 consecutive integers for that i have created below this. Right now i want to find the product of 7,3,1,6 and store the product is 126, i want to be able to print each product out before the next line. Any help?

I am not sure what to use to find the product after each sublist as it iterates through the for loop, how do i find the product of a sublist?  I did try something but it only gives me 126 over and over

```
         for (int z = 0; z < 1000; z++) {
            System.out.println(list.subList(z, z + 4));

            int prod = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.subList(z, z + 4).size(); i++) { // i indexes each
                                                                    // element
                                                                    // successively.
                prod = prod * list.get(i);
            }

            System.out.println(prod);

 [7, 3, 1, 6]
  126
 [3, 1, 6, 7]
  126
 [1, 6, 7, 1]
  126
 {6, 7, 1, 7]
  126
 [7, 1, 7, 6]
```

Comment: And...? What is your question?

Comment: iterate on all lines and compare the product with the max found

Comment: @Kayaman how do i find the product of a sublist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand what you want, you can do this with Java 8 :

```
for (int z = 0; z < list.size() - 4; z++) 
    System.out.println(list.subList(z, z + 4).stream().reduce((i,j) -> i*j));
```

Edit :

Since you can't use Java 8, this one doesn't use lambdas :

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,6,9,4,2,9,7,2,8);
for (int z = 0; z < list.size() - 4; z++) {
    List<Integer> sublist = list.subList(z, z + 4);
    int           prod    = 1;
    for (int i : sublist)
        prod *= i;
    System.out.println(prod);
}
```

Comment: i am not how to store a sublist to find the product.

Comment: Did you read my code ? The product is computed... Plus, you could do that very easily with a simple loop over the sublist.

Comment: for (int z = 0; z < 1000; z++) {
    System.out.println(list.subList(z, z + 4));
    
    int prod = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.subList(z, z + 4).size(); i++) { // i indexes each
                  // element
                  // successively.
     prod = prod * list.get(i);
    }

    System.out.println(prod);

Comment: I did but it gives me 126 over and over

Comment: i dont have java 8 and i trying to to find a genric solution rather than a fancy one to help become a better programmer

Comment: THANK YOU! I have been beaating myself up over how to store a stupic sublist all along

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else already said, this is pretty basic stuff, and functional programming is more fun that loops for sure.

Anyway (assumption is that sublist must have exactly four elements):

```
import java.util.*;

class SO_25107869
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      try {
         final List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList( 1, 2, 3, 4, 10,10,10,10, 3, 2, 1 );
         List<Integer> max_window = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
         if (list.size() < 4) {
            System.err.println("list too small");
            System.exit(1);
         }
         long max_sum =Long.MIN_VALUE;
         for (int z=0; z<list.size(); z++) {
            if (z <= (list.size()-4)) {
               final List<Integer> window = list.subList(z,z+4);
               long sum = 0L;
               for ( int x : window ) { sum += x; }
               if (sum > max_sum) {
                  max_sum = sum;
                  max_window = window;
               }
            }
         }
         System.out.println(max_window+" sum:"+max_sum);
         System.exit(0);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(1);
      }
   }
}
```